# MyPy complains about Qt.AlignmentFlag

Tags: qt, pyside6

When I upgrade to PySide6 6.2.2, MyPy starts complaining about `Qt.AlignmentFlag`. Here's a small example:

```
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication

app = QApplication()
label = QLabel("Hello, World!")
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
label.show()

app.exec()
```

That still runs fine, but MyPy complains:

```
$ mypy foo.py 
foo.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "setAlignment" of "QLabel" has incompatible type "AlignmentFlag"; expected "Alignment"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
$
```

OK, I try converting the `AlignmentFlag` to an `Alignment`.

```
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication

app = QApplication()
label = QLabel("Hello, World!")
label.setAlignment(Qt.Alignment(Qt.AlignCenter))
label.show()

app.exec()
```

Again, that runs fine, but MyPy now complains about the constructor.

```
$ mypy foo.py 
foo.py:6: error: Too many arguments for "Alignment"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
$
```

Could someone please explain how to use `Qt.Alignment` and `Qt.AlignmentFlag`?

Answer (score 2):

Until I find a better option, I'm going to assume that someone messed up the type hints in PySide6 6.2.2, and I'll just tell MyPy to ignore it.

```
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication

app = QApplication()
label = QLabel("Hello, World!")
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)  # type: ignore
label.show()

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter` instead of `Qt.AlignCenter` in the `setAlignment` function? PySide/PyQt fills that field with the enum value you want at runtime, to have some similarity to how you would do it in C++.

`Qt.AlignmentFlag` is an enum class and `AlignCenter` is an enum value.

Comment: Same problem Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter is of type AlginmentFlag, the method expects "Alignment" type,
though a thing to note is, I noticed the issue dissappered using the OP code

Comment: @IyadAhmed Probably another thing PySide does at runtime, I don't know, I've only used PyQt